# Zooming in on imageview in Android without quality loss

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, zooming

I need to pinch zoom and drag/pan an image, so i implemented a scaleimageview.
but the more i zoom in, the more blurry the image gets.
I'm searching almost 3 days now for a solution.
My code looks like this (i'm using Xamarin for Android):

```
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace test
{

public class ScaleImageViewGestureDetector : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    private readonly ScaleImageView m_ScaleImageView;
    public ScaleImageViewGestureDetector(ScaleImageView imageView)
    {
        m_ScaleImageView = imageView;
    }

    public override bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
    {
        m_ScaleImageView.MaxZoomTo((int)e.GetX(), (int)e.GetY());
        m_ScaleImageView.Cutting();
        return true;
    }
}

public class ScaleImageView : ImageView, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private Context m_Context;

    private float m_MaxScale = 2.0f;

    private Matrix m_Matrix;
    private float[] m_MatrixValues = new float[9];
    private int m_Width;
    private int m_Height;
    private int m_IntrinsicWidth;
    private int m_IntrinsicHeight;
    private float m_Scale;
    private float m_MinScale;
    private float m_PreviousDistance;
    private int m_PreviousMoveX;
    private int m_PreviousMoveY;
    private bool m_IsScaling;
    private GestureDetector m_GestureDetector;

    public ScaleImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
    base(context, attrs)
    {
        m_Context = context;
        Initialize();
    }

    public ScaleImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
    base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        m_Context = context;
        Initialize();
    }

    public override void SetImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        base.SetImageBitmap(bm);
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public override void SetImageResource(int resId)
    {
        base.SetImageResource(resId);
        this.Initialize();
    }


    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.SetScaleType(ScaleType.Matrix);
        m_Matrix = new Matrix();

        if (Drawable != null)
        {
            m_IntrinsicWidth = Drawable.IntrinsicWidth;
            m_IntrinsicHeight = Drawable.IntrinsicHeight;
            this.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        m_GestureDetector = new GestureDetector(m_Context, new ScaleImageViewGestureDetector(this));
    }

    protected override bool SetFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b)//left top right bottom
    {
        m_Width = r - l;
        m_Height = b - t;

        Console.WriteLine ("test");
        Console.WriteLine (m_Width.ToString ());
        Console.WriteLine (m_Height.ToString ());

        m_Matrix.Reset();

        var r_norm = r - l;
        m_Scale = (float)r_norm / (float)m_IntrinsicWidth;

        ImageMatrix = m_Matrix;

        double height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        double width = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;

        float scaleFactor = (float)(height/m_IntrinsicHeight);

        //don't take screen height, there's a tabbar on the bottom of the screen!
        m_Matrix.PostTranslate( (float) ((width-m_IntrinsicWidth)/2.00f),(float) ((m_Height-m_IntrinsicHeight)/2.00f)); 

        m_MinScale = scaleFactor;
        ZoomTo(m_Scale, m_Width / 2, m_Height / 2);
        Cutting();
        return base.SetFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    private float GetValue(Matrix matrix, int whichValue)
    {
        matrix.GetValues(m_MatrixValues);
        return m_MatrixValues[whichValue];
    }



    public float Scale
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(m_Matrix, Matrix.MscaleX); }
    }

    public float TranslateX
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(m_Matrix, Matrix.MtransX); }
    }

    public float TranslateY
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(m_Matrix, Matrix.MtransY); }
    }

    public void MaxZoomTo(int x, int y)
    {
        if (this.m_MinScale != this.Scale && (Scale - m_MinScale) > 0.1f)
        {
            var scale = m_MinScale / Scale;
            ZoomTo(scale, x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            var scale = m_MaxScale / Scale;
            ZoomTo(scale, x, y);
        }
    }

    public void ZoomTo(float scale, int x, int y)
    {
        if (Scale * scale < m_MinScale)
        {
            scale = m_MinScale / Scale;
        }
        else
        {
            if (scale >= 1 && Scale * scale > m_MaxScale)
            {
                scale = m_MaxScale / Scale;
            }
        }
        m_Matrix.PostScale(scale, scale);
        //move to center
        m_Matrix.PostTranslate(-(m_Width * scale - m_Width) / 2, -(m_Height * scale - m_Height) / 2);

        //move x and y distance
        m_Matrix.PostTranslate(-(x - (m_Width / 2)) * scale, 0);
        m_Matrix.PostTranslate(0, -(y - (m_Height / 2)) * scale);
        ImageMatrix = m_Matrix;
    }

    public void Cutting()
    {
        var width = (int)(m_IntrinsicWidth * Scale);
        var height = (int)(m_IntrinsicHeight * Scale);

        if (TranslateX < -(width - m_Width))
        {
            m_Matrix.PostTranslate(-(TranslateX + width - m_Width), 0);
        }

        if (TranslateX > 0)
        {
            m_Matrix.PostTranslate(-TranslateX, 0);
        }

        if (TranslateY < -(height - m_Height))
        {
            m_Matrix.PostTranslate(0, -(TranslateY + height - m_Height));
        }

        if (TranslateY > 0)
        {
            m_Matrix.PostTranslate(0, -TranslateY);
        }

        if (width < m_Width)
        {
            m_Matrix.PostTranslate((m_Width - width) / 2, 0);
        }

        if (height < m_Height)
        {
            m_Matrix.PostTranslate(0, (m_Height - height) / 2);
        }

        ImageMatrix = m_Matrix;
    }

    private float Distance(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1)
    {
        var x = x0 - x1;
        var y = y0 - y1;
        return FloatMath.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private float DispDistance()
    {
        return FloatMath.Sqrt(m_Width * m_Width + m_Height * m_Height);
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (m_GestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e))
        {
            m_PreviousMoveX = (int)e.GetX();
            m_PreviousMoveY = (int)e.GetY();
            return true;
        }

        var touchCount = e.PointerCount;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Down:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer2Down:
            {
                if (touchCount >= 2)
                {
                    var distance = this.Distance(e.GetX(0), e.GetX(1), e.GetY(0), e.GetY(1));
                    m_PreviousDistance = distance;
                    m_IsScaling = true;
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            {
                if (touchCount >= 2 && m_IsScaling)
                {
                    var distance = this.Distance(e.GetX(0), e.GetX(1), e.GetY(0), e.GetY(1));
                    var scale = (distance - m_PreviousDistance) / this.DispDistance();
                    m_PreviousDistance = distance;
                    scale += 1;
                    scale = scale * scale;
                    this.ZoomTo(scale, m_Width / 2, m_Height / 2);
                    this.Cutting();
                }
                else if (!m_IsScaling)
                {
                    var distanceX = m_PreviousMoveX - (int)e.GetX();
                    var distanceY = m_PreviousMoveY - (int)e.GetY();
                    m_PreviousMoveX = (int)e.GetX();
                    m_PreviousMoveY = (int)e.GetY();

                    m_Matrix.PostTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                    this.Cutting();
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Up:
        case MotionEventActions.Pointer2Up:
            {
                if (touchCount <= 1)
                {
                    m_IsScaling = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return OnTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use this class https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

Comment: will i lose image quality when zooming in?

Comment: I would imagine you'd lose image quality regardless of what library you use. The more you zoom, the bigger your pixels become (unless you interpolate them which will introduce problems with aliasing). It's no different than digital zooms. You have a finite number of pixels and when you zoom, you're effectively showing less original pixels by enlarging existing pixels or dividing each pixel into 4-9 pixels and using an interpolation function to guess their color. Both techniques will produce artifacts and will reduce details.